# Self-referential use of unordered_map causes problems for gcc 5.3 but not clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang++, libstdc++, libc++

The following code fails to compile under *gcc 5.3* (it's a reduced version taken from a larger piece of code):

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

class Foo {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo> m;  //"self-referential"
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    return 0;
}
```

with the following errors:

```
g++ --std=c++1y  -c rh.cpp

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/utility:70:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/unordered_map:38,
                 from rh.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<const int, Foo>’:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/ext/aligned_buffer.h:85:34:   required from ‘struct __gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<std::pair<const int, Foo> >’
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:246:43:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base<std::pair<const int, Foo> >’
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:292:12:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Foo>, false>’
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1896:60:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, Foo>, false> > >’
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/hashtable.h:170:11:   required from ‘class std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<const int, Foo>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Foo> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >’
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/unordered_map.h:101:18:   required from ‘class std::unordered_map<int, Foo>’
rh.cpp:4:32:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:102:11: error: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second’ has incomplete type
       _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
           ^
rh.cpp:3:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class Foo’
 class Foo {
```

There is no issue with the code using *clang* (I tested 3.8 on Linux, and 3.9 on OSX):

`clang++ --std=c++1y --stdlib=libc++ -c rh.cpp`

On linux, using *clang* + *libstdc++* also fails.

The issue seems to come down to *libstdc++* using an `__gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer` in its hash map implementation, which needs a complete type.

Both standard libraries work fine when a *std::map* is used, but that is not a solution I can accept. Nor is having the value type of the map be a pointer to *Foo*.

Is there any other change that I can make to have the code work on *gcc/libstdc++*?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you turn the `m` into the pointer itself?

Comment: that could be an approach, but I can't figure out how to make it work.  Once I make `m` a pointer, gcc is happy, but as soon as I try to call new in a constructor e.g. `Foo(): m(new std::unordered_map<int, Foo>()) {}`, I face the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to modify *Foo* class in the next manner:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
private:
    using MapType = std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo>;
    std::shared_ptr<MapType> m_ptr;
};

// Here Foo is already defined.
Foo::Foo() {
    m_ptr = std::make_shared<MapType>();
}
```

This code compiles fine with both [clang 3.9](https://godbolt.org/g/hS5etK) and [gcc 6.2](https://godbolt.org/g/RML8p1).

Comment: I'd have gone with `unique_ptr` myself, which would have highlighted the need to write a custom copy constructor.

Comment: @hvd I didn't think much about the type of the ptr, just something which helps to avoid custom memory management. Anyway, then main idea was to show how to rearrange the code to avoid compilation problems.